# trying to find a javascript dropdown control

Tags: javascript, controls, widget

I'm looking for a dropdown similar to the openid site-select dropdown on the stackoverflow login page:

[image]
<sub>(source: [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/openid-1-login-helper.png))</sub>

... and for now I'd rather not sit down and write one myself. I'm looking for one written for inclusion in plain html/javascript (php code), must be free for commercial use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dozens of [jquery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/dropdown+type:project_project) that you may find commercial worthy.

Comment: Is jquery usable with plain html / php?

Comment: JQuery is a JavaScript library. So I'd say 'yes'.